# Facebook and Twitter APIs for Window Phone 7

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, windows-7, twitter

Is there any APIs available that can be used for login in facebook and twitter accounts. If yes then please give the code or Please reference any website which have details about this.

Answer (score 0):

Tweetsharp has a nice WP7 library. The project seems to be down at the moment though.

Answer (score 0):

How about the [Facebook SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/)?  Scott Guthrie has a full, simple [Twitter example on his blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/18/building-a-windows-phone-7-twitter-application-using-silverlight.aspx).